# python blur detection using opencv is not working

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am using below code and attached blurred image, but is not detecting image has blurred

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def detect_blur_fft(image, threshold=100):
    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Compute the FFT
    fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(gray))
    
    # Calculate the magnitude spectrum
    magnitude_spectrum = np.abs(fft)
    
    # Calculate the mean magnitude
    mean_magnitude = np.mean(magnitude_spectrum)
    
    # If the mean magnitude is below the threshold, image is considered blurred
    if mean_magnitude < threshold:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# For images
image_path = '/Users/tamcv/Downloads/blurred-background-vintage-filter-customer-coffee-shop-blur-background-with-bokeh.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
if detect_blur_fft(image):
    print("Image is blurred.")
else:
    print("Image is not blurred.")
```

Expected output:  Image is blurred.

Actual output: Image is not blurred.

Ask: If any issue with code please help to fix or is there any better tooling to detect blur of images and videos

Comment: Well, this is not an exact operation.  There is no sharp line that divides "blurred" and "not blurred".  That's why there is a threshold value.  You need to adjust the threshold so it works for your images.

Comment: @TimRoberts In this case we need to upload example images and train them?

Comment: Well, train it manually.  Try a few and adjust the threshold until it works for you.  Do you understand what the code is trying to do mathematically?

Comment: @TimRoberts, no  I did not understand, I got code somewhere in the internet and trying

Comment: taking the mean of all the magnitudes is silly. you need to assess *which* frequencies are present by how much. lack of high frequencies characterizes a blur. -- you "found a code on the internet"? we can't help with that. you have to be able to understand code and debug it. [tour], [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the magnitude, you have to inverse the fft.

See blog [OpenCV Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) for blur detection in images and video streams](https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/06/15/opencv-fast-fourier-transform-fft-for-blur-detection-in-images-and-video-streams/)

I modified your function like that :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# original function
def detect_blur_fft(image, threshold=100):
    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Compute the FFT
    fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(gray))
    
    # Calculate the magnitude spectrum
    magnitude_spectrum = np.abs(fft)
    
    # Calculate the mean magnitude
    mean_magnitude = np.mean(magnitude_spectrum)
   
    # If the mean magnitude is below the threshold, image is considered blurred
    if mean_magnitude < threshold:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# modified function
def detect_blur_fft2(image_path, size=60, thresh=20, vis=False):
    
    # read the imaghe
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        
    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
    # grab the dimensions of the image and use the dimensions to
    # derive the center (x, y)-coordinates
    (h, w) = gray.shape
    (cX, cY) = (int(w / 2.0), int(h / 2.0))
    
    # compute the FFT to find the frequency transform, then shift
    # the zero frequency component (i.e., DC component located at
    # the top-left corner) to the center where it will be more
    # easy to analyze
    fft = np.fft.fft2(gray)
    fftShift = np.fft.fftshift(fft)
    fftShift[cY - size:cY + size, cX - size:cX + size] = 0
    recon = np.fft.ifft2(fftShift)
    
    # check to see if we are visualizing our output
    if vis:
        # compute the magnitude spectrum of the transform
        magnitude = 20 * np.log(np.abs(fftShift))
        # display the original input image
        (fig, ax) = plt.subplots(1, 2,)
        ax[0].imshow(gray , cmap="gray")
        ax[0].set_title("Input")
        ax[0].set_xticks([])
        ax[0].set_yticks([])
        # display the magnitude image
        ax[1].imshow(magnitude, cmap="gray")
        ax[1].set_title("Magnitude Spectrum")
        ax[1].set_xticks([])
        ax[1].set_yticks([])
        
        # show our plots
        plt.show()
        
    # compute the magnitude spectrum of the reconstructed image,
    # then compute the mean of the magnitude values
    magnitude = 20 * np.log(np.abs(recon))
    mean = np.mean(magnitude)
    # the image will be considered "blurry" if the mean value of the
    # magnitudes is less than the threshold value
    if  mean < thresh:
        print(f"Image {image_path} is blurred. (mean={mean} < thresh={thresh})")
    else:
        print(f"Image {image_path}is not blurred. (mean={mean} >= thresh={thresh})")
    
# For images

detect_blur_fft2('no-blurred-image.jpg',thresh=20)
detect_blur_fft2('blurred-10pct-image.jpg',thresh=20)
detect_blur_fft2('blurred-25pct-image.jpg',thresh=20)
detect_blur_fft2('blurred-50pct-image.jpg',thresh=20)
```

Results :

```
Image no-blurred-image.jpgis not blurred. (mean=32.10492880802149 >= thresh=20)
Image blurred-10pct-image.jpg is blurred. (mean=-2.830913603846185 < thresh=20)
Image blurred-25pct-image.jpg is blurred. (mean=-14.551034649524599 < thresh=20)
Image blurred-50pct-image.jpg is blurred. (mean=-14.650873079711776 < thresh=20)
```

[no-blurred-image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w1dh.jpg)

[blurred-10pct-image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJFMc.jpg)

[blurred-25pct-image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaHPk.jpg)

[blurred-50pct-image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1MLB.jpg)

Comment: That doesn't particularly make sense to me.  When an image is blurry, it has strong low frequency and weak high-frequency components.  An FFT allows you to check that.  Inverting the FFT takes us back to pixels.  Why would the average pixel value be meaningful?